# How can I put '-' between words in this code php?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Below code will echo like this

```
('nice apple'),(' nice yellow banana'),(' good berry  ')
```

what I need to do is that I need them to be like this

```
('nice-apple'),(' nice-yellow-banana'),(' good-berry  ')
```

The challenge is that I could not touch $str, and then I need to use '-' to connect words if there is space between them, If use str_replace space, it will be something like ----nice-apple-. how can I achieve something like this ('nice-apple'), appreciate.

```
<?php
$str="nice apple,
  nice yellow banana,    
  good berry 
 ";

echo $str = "('" . implode("'),('", explode(',', $str)) . "')";
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `str_replace`

```
$str="nice apple,
  nice yellow banana,    
  good berry 
 ";

$str = array_map(function($dr){ return preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', trim($dr));},explode(',',$str));
$str = implode(',',$str);

echo $str = "('" . implode("'),('", explode(',', $str)) . "')";
```

Output:

```
('nice-apple'),('nice-yellow-banana'),('good-berry')
```

Comment: You changed the input to remove all the extra spaces that caused the problem

Comment: Oh I thought he placed it in that way for better view

Answer (score 0):

you need to get rid of the new lines first then it'll work.

```
<?php
$str="nice apple,
  nice yellow banana,
  good berry
 ";

$arr = explode(',', str_replace([ "\r\n", "\n" ], "", $str));

$arrCount = sizeOf($arr);

for($x = 0; $x < $arrCount; $x++) {
    while (preg_match('/(\w)\s(\w)/', $arr[$x])) {
        $arr[$x] = preg_replace('/(\w)\s(\w)/', '$1-$2', $arr[$x]);
    }
}



echo $str = "('" . implode("'),('", $arr) . "')";
?>
```

`('nice-apple'),('      nice-yellow-banana'),('      good-berry     ')`

Comment: You haven't put hyphens between the words. Did you read the question?

Comment: yes yes, I just realized the moment I posted update coming in 30 secs.

Comment: oh I see you already accepted, I thought you wanted to keep the spaces so I wrote the code to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Its bit tricky. Try with -

```
$str="('nice apple'),(' nice yellow banana'),(' good berry  ')";

$v = explode(',', $str); // generate an array by exploding the string by `,`
foreach($v as $key => $val) {
  $temp = trim(str_replace(["(", "'", ")"], "", $val)); //remove the brackets and trim the string
  $v[$key] = "('".str_replace(" ", "-", $temp)."')"; // place the `-`s
}
$new = implode(",", $v); // implode them again
var_dump($new);
```